Django Admin automatically logs me out when i click the save button and won't allow me log in again
Whenever I click the save button to add user on the django admin interface, it automatically logs me out and won't re-authenticate me despite being the superuser.
The design pattern: I created a class called CustomUser which inherited the django AbstractUser and another class UserProfile model which has OneToOneField to the settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL(main.CustomUser) and added some common fields among the student, parent and staff(e.g other_name), then student, staff and parent class inherited the UserProfile and I added their specific field. So I do add a user first, then go to the student model to add the user as a student.
main is my app_name.
Kindly help with on this as I have deadline which is near. I'll provide more details and code on request
settings.py
from pathlib import Path
import os
import secrets
from django.conf.urls import handler403

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-!&740lo5u6#-@c9d80ab*-!k1-8f$fu@r*3xp5ytke)7t+dwy+'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

# SESSION_TIMEOUT_SECONDS = 120
USER_SESSION_KEY = secrets.token_hex(32)
# ADMIN_SESSION_KEY = secrets.token_hex(32)
# PARENT_SESSION_KEY = secrets.token_hex(32)
SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.db'  # Store sessions in the database
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 1209600  # 2 weeks
SESSION_COOKIE_NAME = 'sessionid'
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = False
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE=False


AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'main.CustomUser'
ROOT_URLCONF = 'ahc_website.urls'
LOGIN_URL = '/login/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/dashboard/'
handler403 = 'main.views.permission_denied_view'
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # CUSTOM APPS
    'main',
    'background_task',
    'jazzmin',
    
    
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

models.py
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    pass
    
    
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    other_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
class Student(UserProfile):
    student_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    parents = models.ManyToManyField(Parent, verbose_name="Parent Name", related_name="children", blank=True)

forms.py
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password1', 'password2', 'is_active', 'groups')
        exclude = ['user', 'session', 'term', 'user_type']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['password1'].label = 'Password'
        self.fields['password2'].label = 'Confirm Password'

    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user

class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = "__all__"

admin.py
class CustomUserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm
    form = CustomUserChangeForm
    model = CustomUser
    list_display = ['username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_staff']
    
    fieldsets = (
            (None, {'fields': ('username', 'password')}),
            ('Personal info', {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')}),
            ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'is_active', 'groups', 'user_permissions')}),
            ('Important dates', {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}),
        )
        
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('username', 'password1', 'password2', 'email'),
        }),
    )

        
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if not change:  # If creating a new user
            obj.set_password(form.cleaned_data['password1'])
        else:  # If updating an existing user
            if 'password' in form.cleaned_data and form.cleaned_data['password']:
                obj.set_password(form.cleaned_data['password'])
            elif 'password1' in form.cleaned_data and form.cleaned_data['password1']:
                obj.set_password(form.cleaned_data['password1'])
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)

class StudentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = StudentForm
    list_display = ['user', 'student_id']

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if not change:
            user = form.cleaned_data['user']
            user.set_password('defaultpassword')
            user.save()
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)

Tried to save student in the django admin interface
expected the user to be saved and be redirected to all users.
Note: when i created another superuser and logs in, I notice I've be redirected to users page. If try the same operation again, I get logged out and can't log in again.
